# Which US allies ignored the USA's call for stopping the import of Russian oil and gas?

Tags: russian-federation, gas, oil

Which US allies ignored the USA's call for stopping the import of Russian oil and gas and continued importing them till today?

Comment: Are we making a distinction between ignoring a call, and hearing it but choosing to do otherwise? If not, that's quite a dramatic phrasing.

Comment: What exactly was he US's call? There is a big difference between "Stop all Russian gas imports immediately!" and "Continue to phase out Russian gas imports as much as possible!"

Comment: What's your definition of ally? Nato members, countries with a military assistance treaty, countries with other military arrangements (e.g. bases), countries that are commonly described in the media as allies, or something else?

Answer (score 5):

Turkey and Hungary are both NATO members, but still importing Russian oil and gas. Also there is still transit of Russian gas through Ukraine to Europe, which means that European allies have reduced import of Russian oil and gas, but haven't completely stopped it.

Also, according to [this article](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-11933643/Biden-gives-permission-Japan-buy-Russian-oil-60-barrel-cap.html), Japan is another country closely allied with USA buying Russian oil.

Comment: In April 2023 the US imported something like 215 million USD of Russian oil. https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/imports-from-russia

Answer (score 0):

Austria is one such country, and it intends to continue importing gas from Russia. The following article from the Financial Times also reports on this.

[Austria’s OMV to continue to import Russian gas, chief says](https://www.ft.com/content/304034be-9cd5-406d-b668-894c4eac5a76)

> The Vienna-based energy company’s contract with Gazprom runs until
> 2040
>
> Austrian energy group OMV will continue to buy most of its gas from
> Russia this winter, its chief executive has said, even though the
> company has secured back-up contracts to fully cover its import needs
> from other sources.
>
> Alfred Stern said that, 18 months after Russia’s invasion of Ukraine,
> his company was not making any plans to try to exit its long-term
> supply contract with Russia’s Gazprom, which it signed in 2018.
> Russian gas is not subject to western sanctions.
>
> “As long as Gazprom will supply . . . we will continue to take these
> quantities from Gazprom,” Stern said in an interview with the
> Financial Times.

Comment: Welcome to Politics! Please don't post answers which only consist of a quote, see [our help center page on referencing material by others](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Since this answer is just a quote and contains none of your own words to answer the question, I will delete it for now in line with the linked policy. Feel free to flag it for undeletion after editing per the guidance in the help center link.

Comment: Please note this part specifically: *"Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content."*